osqueryd using 90% of cpu for extended periods of time
I have a Ubuntu server that has osqueryd installed through Sophos-SPL. Every few weeks the service will sit with 90% cpu until restarted, how can I fix and prevent this?

To fix the problem quickly (source):

Stop the service with systemctl stop sophos-spl
Clear the OSQuery database with rm -rf /opt/sophos-spl/plugins/edr/var/osquery.db/*
Start the process with systemctl start sophos-spl

They also have some tips to prevent the issue on a forum thread. It'll take a bit of tweaking depending on your system:

Stop the service with systemctl stop sophos-spl
Open the file at /opt/sophos-spl/plugins/edr/etc/plugin.conf
Add the following lines, customizing values as needed (defaults provided):
events_max=100000
watchdog_memory_limit=250
watchdog_utilization_limit=30
watchdog_latency_limit=0
watchdog_delay=60

You can find more information on the flags in the osquery docs.
Start the service with systemctl start sophos-spl
Check that the values have changed in /opt/sophos-spl/plugins/edr/etc/osquery.flags

